# Is it possible to change the whitelist urls submitted

Tags: google-cast

I have got my URLs whitelisted, however I've realized they are not really ideal. Is it possible to get them changed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write to Chromecast-updates@google.com.  Please include your AppID.

Comment: Thanks, I did that and the response was "Yes, it can be done, please use the same page that you used to submit your whitelisting request and provide your updated URLs and we'll make the change."